# Why is "wpa_supplicant.conf" file invisible?

Tags: wi-fi, internal-storage, root-access, privacy, password

My device **LG e510 : Android 2.3** had been rooted and then I changed the privileges to view and see some system files, especially for **wpa_supplicant.conf**, with RootExplorer app.

But unlike most people, I can not see the file inside /data/misc/wifi/ directory, it's empty and /system/etc directory has **wpa_supplicant.conf** header information file.

Lastly I used WifiPassRecovery app, and the app immediatelly retrieved all the saved wifi passwords.

Where did this app retrieve all those informations? and Why cannot I see the file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Found them in

```
/data/misc/apexdata/com.android.wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml
```

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Since manufacturers can and do customize their Android, could you [edit] and also mention the device model and Android version, just in case it matters?

Comment: It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

On the Galaxy S, the credentials are stored in `/data/wifi/bcm_supp.conf` (where bcm is short for Broadcom).  Other common locations include `/data/wifi/`, `/data/etc/wifi/` and `/data/misc/wifi/` — check them for relevant config files.